# cacti default port

Tags: cacti

I used apt-get to install cacti on my ubuntu 10.04 box. It said it installed correctly, but I'm not sure what port its listening on.

Comment: I know that the documentation says its http://myserver.com/cacti. But nothing comes up at that address.

Answer (score 3):

Try using `http://localhost/cacti`.  None of the docs (that I have found, at least) reference a specific port, so I'd assume that it's listening on the default http port (80).

If nothing else, you can [use netcat to scan your machine](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=1984202&postcount=7) for open ports before and after launching cacti.  Any ports that change between the two scans are probably in use by cacti.